# Calculate in join in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to achieve staggered calculation in joins in sql 2008. I can have n number of rows for 1 job id. I have created a sample below

```
CREATE TABLE Job
(
  JobID INT NOT NULL,
  Amount INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Job (JobID, Amount)
    VALUES (1, 25),
        (1, 45),
        (1, 40),
        (2, 25),
        (3, 26),
        (3, 26);
```

now the discount for `JobID = 1` is 80 , So what I am expecting in output of query result is below:

If the `Amount > Discount` , so show the `finalvalue = Amount - Discount`
but if `Amount < Discount` , then show `Finalvalue = Amount - Amount` ,
and if `Discount` is still left , deduct the same from the subsequent rows.

```
Job ID  Amount  FinalValue
1        25       0
1        45       0
1        40      30
```

Can all this be done in a join?

Comment: Please include the structure of your discount table so a proper answer can be formulated.

Comment: Do you have an ID or creation date field that can be used to tell the order in which the discount should be applied?  For example, in your example, how did you decide to apply the discount to the 25 and 45 rows before you applied it to the 40 row?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

EDIT: ATTENTION: You should add a column for sorting. My approach is partitioning AND sorting by JobID which makes the output random...

EDIT: Sorry, did not add the tables...

```
CREATE TABLE Job
(
    JobID INT NOT NULL,
    Amount INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Job (JobID, Amount)
    VALUES (1, 25), (1, 45), (1, 40), (2, 25), (3, 26), (3, 26);

CREATE TABLE Discount
(
    JobID INT NOT NULL,
    Discount INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Discount(JobID,Discount)VALUES(1,80),(2,0),(3,10);
    WITH myCTE AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Job.JobID ORDER BY Job.JobID) AS inx
              ,Job.JobID
              ,Job.Amount
              ,Discount.Discount     
        FROM Job
        INNER JOIN Discount ON Job.JobID=Discount.JobID
    )
    SELECT * FROM myCTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM(x.Amount)
        FROM myCTE AS x
        WHERE x.JobID=myCTE.JobID
          AND x.inx<=myCTE.inx  
    ) AS AmountCummulativ(AmountCummulativ)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT AmountCummulativ-myCTE.Discount) AS DiscountCalculated(DiscountCalculated)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN DiscountCalculated<0 THEN 0 ELSE DiscountCalculated END) AS DiscountResolved(DiscountResolved)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be done using a case statement

```
select a.jobid,a.Amount,case when a.amount > b.discount then a.amount - b.discount else 0 end final_value
```

from Job a inner join Job_discount b on a.jobid = b.jobid

You can look at the results here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9a46/1

I had to assume the discount table structure

Comment: Does your SQLFiddle really return the OP's data? I understood the OP in a way that there is a cummulation of amount to be done, Better word than "Discount" could be "Acconto"...

Comment: Vanamali, Apppreciate ur efforts...but I thnk u r juss flatly subtracting the discount from amount...thts nt the case..u have to take care for all the line items...

Answer (score 0):

I added some sequence (row number) for the Job table (calling it JobOrder), to increment the sums. You can change the order as it is now for JobId, Amount!

```
With JobOrder as (
  -- Job order by id and amount
  select row_number() over (order by JobID, Amount asc) as rowno, JobId, Amount from Job
),
JobSumIncr as (
  select 
  JobID, 
  Amount, 
  (select sum(Amount)
   from JobOrder j2
   where j2.JobID = j.JobID and j2.RowNo <= j.RowNo
  ) as AmountTotal
  from JobOrder j
)
select 
  j.JobID,
  j.Amount,
  j.AmountTotal,
  d.Discount,
  (case when d.Discount>=j.AmountTotal then 0 else j.AmountTotal-d.Discount end) as FinalValue
from
  JobSumIncr j left join Discount d on j.JobID = d.JobID;
```

Asuming that your Discount table is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Discount (
    JobID INT,
    Discount INT 
);
```

**[SqlFiddle here!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f705f/2)** and for a more secure Sql (checking null values and see the discount left) see this **[SQLFiddle too](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b8d6/1)**.

[image]

A version which keeps track of the discount left, see sqlfiddle-2 above.

[image]

Comment: Hi Simple, Thans for your efforts..Your answer is quite close  but it breaks in few scenarios...eg If I add another row in JOB table like (1,50)...It will break ..Till the point the discount left is nt becoming 0 , your query works like a treat...

Comment: Hi @XanderKage I don't understand your comment. How will it break in adding another amount of 50 to jobid 1 ? I checked in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58efd7/1 and it works like charm, the discountleft matches and the finalvalue is correct ;) or did you expect that the finalvalue incr too? like for jobid 1 it will go like 0, 0, 30, and then 50?

Comment: HI SImple, my bad .. it works correctly but I found 1 situation where it breaks :( Lets suppose the discount is  less that lowest amount..in tha scenario it breaks... I  updated the discount as 5 for JOB ID = 4 to test it... Appreciate your efforts  tho..

Comment: Can you explain more. What amount to do you have in the Job table for jobid 4? and is there any discount for jobid 4? you write discount 5 is for jobid4, but what amounts in the job tble ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code :  80 is the discount amount

```
Select JobID,  Amount,
case when SUM (Amount) OVER (partition by JobID ORDER BY JobID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > 80 then SUM(Amount) OVER (partition by JobID ORDER BY JobID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 80 else 0 end as FinalValue
from Job
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.